# Discord py TypeError: on_member_join() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'after' and 'member' when someone joins the server

Tags: python, discord.py

I made discord bot that should give someone role upon joining but I get error which can be seen here:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\jarda\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 409, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: on_member_join() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'after' and 'member'
```

And almost full code is here:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.utils import get
from discord.ext.commands import Bot


intents = discord.Intents.all()
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!", intents=intents)

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('We have logged in as {0.user}'.format(client))
 
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content.startswith("AboutMe"):
        await message.channel.send("Hello world!")

@client.event 
async def on_member_join(before, after, member):
    channel=client.get_channel(channelID)
    emb=discord.Embed(title="New member has joined",description=f"Thanks {member.mention} for being part of the bros!")
    await channel.send(embed=emb)
    print(f"{member.name} has joined the server")

#Adds role

    TheGreatLegendWarriors = Bot.get_guild(serverID)
    if 'inTraining' in after.roles:
        if not 'inTraining' in str(before.roles):
            await after.add_roles(discord.utils.get(TheGreatLegendWarriors.roles, name="inTraining"))
            print(f"INFO: {after.name} Has been given inTraining role!")
```

Iam new to py and discord api so really unsure what the issue is. I tried using 2 on_member_join which gave me error as 2 of those can't run at the same time. Then this appeared and I have struggled for way too long now.

Comment: Your code looks like you want to be using `on_member_update` instead of `on_member_join`...?

Answer (score 2):

The docs [specify](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=on_member_join#discord.on_member_join) that `on_member_join` should accept a single parameter, `member`.

You can remove the `before` and `after` parameters from your `on_member_join` function signature.

Comment: That gives another error - Unidentified variable (after, before) on lines 34, 34, 36, and 37.

Comment: `member.roles` should also give you the user's new roles. Maybe also ask the person who originally wrote this code how come it worked for them? Or where did you get it from?

Comment: The code is my for the most part - I used older posts on here and this seemed as viable option so I rolled with it. Ill try the member.role and ill see if it works.

Comment: Maybe the posts you found use an older version of Discord Py. Hard to tell without seeing the source.

Comment: Well, I have used the member.roles and Iam getting different error "TypeError: Client.get_guild() missing 1 required positional argument: 'id' " even though Iam using the guild ID.  I think ill be able to move from here myself though. Thanks for help!

Comment: @JardexX you need to call `get_guild` on an **instance** of `Bot`. `Bot` by itself is just the name of a class, you can't use it for anything...